# Why am i not able to use KIF Methods from my own viewController?

Tags: ios, testing, automation, kif

In `ViewController.h` i have used :

```
[tester tapScreenAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.width/2)];
```

No Error at all .

I have included KIF using pod .

The Log i receive is :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
Referenced from:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/43B567B0-B0C2-45F9-9FB6-DAF404EDD14F/TestTap.app/TestTap
Reason: image not found
```

How do i solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions outlined here: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF? What does your podfile look like?

Comment: platform :ios, '7.0'


target 'TestTap' do

pod 'KIF', '~> 3.0'

end

target 'TestTapTests' do

end

target 'TestTapUITests' do

end

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you have KIF included in your app target and not in the test target.

Comment: @duncanc4 yes ! But i dont want to use it from test target . I want to use it run time . Not by manually clicking on particular test scenario .

Comment: I guess you could try manually adding the missing test frameworks that are included with the test target to your main target in Xcode.